# where is the magic, using onSubmit like property in component

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

there is a component that is called sending  onSubmit property

```
import SimpleForm from "./SimpleForm";

 <SimpleForm onSubmit={showResults} />
```

and   the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const SimpleForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
```

where is the magic onSubmit is converted to handleSubmit in props? normally a child component must be read with :  props.onSubmit

is something with redux? i've seen the same without redux-form ...

full code example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/x20j62365o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look, `reduxForm` is a HigherOrderComponent that takes your component and returns a new component which you are exporting as default and using. Think of reduxForm to be implemented in crude form like

```
const reduxForm = (params) => {
   return (Component) => {
       class App extend React.Component {
          render() {
             const {onSubmit} = this.props;
             return <Component handleSubmit={onSubmit} {...otherthingshere}/>
          }
       }

   }
}
```